# Updating xml with variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Let's say we have simple table T1 which has three columns:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(C1 INT PRIMARY KEY, C2 VARCHAR(20), C3 XML)
```

Now we create simple data:

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1, 'Test', '<Element></Element>')
```

Then I want to modify third column to achieve something like this:

```
<Element>Test</Element>
```

Which means, C2 is inserted into XML.

So I wanted to do that with variables:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(20) = 'Example'
UPDATE
     T1
SET 
     @test = C2,
     C3.modify('
     replace value of
     (/Element/text())[1]
     with sql:variable("@test") ')
```

Unfortunately the result is:

```
<Element>Example</Element>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks you're updating and setting your variable at the same time, so the update uses the original value (the value it has when `update` is executed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying the underlying variable in the same statement where it is used; this doesn't work in SQL Server. Either:

Split variable assignment and usage into two separate statements:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(20);

select @test = t.C2
from T1 t;

UPDATE t SET C3.modify('
  replace value of (/Element/text())[1] with sql:variable("@test")
  ')
from T1 t;
```

OR

Use the value of the column directly:

```
UPDATE t SET C3.modify('
  replace value of (/Element/text())[1] with sql:column("t.C2")
  ')
from T1 t;
```

Unless you have some complex logic behind the variable value calculation, the second option is preferred due to performance reasons - you touch the table only once, not twice. Also, the second variant is highly recommended if you need to update more than 1 row, each with different values.

Comment: That what I was looking for. Can you show how can I use two separate statements like you said?